# Why are there multiple libgcc.a shipped with android NDK, which one should be used to link with?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, linker, clang

Android NDK 17 (and I assume earlier versions too), contains multiple versions of `libgcc.a`:

```
android-ndk-r17b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9$ find -iname 
libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/hard/libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/thumb/libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/thumb/hard/libgcc.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/thumb/libgcc.a
```

Same for `libatomic.a`

```
android-ndk-r17b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9$ find -iname libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/hard/libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/hard/libatomic.a
./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/thumb/libatomic.a
```

Each of the containing directories do contain a full set of `crtbegin.o`, `crtend.o` etc...

```
$ ls ./prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/
crtbegin.o  crtbeginS.o  crtbeginT.o  crtend.o  crtendS.o  libgcc.a  libgcov.a
```

Checking each, they are of different size (and I assume content).

- What are the differences between those versions?
- Which of these should be used by the linker to create a valid `.so` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `thumb` refers to the instruction set (most ARM processors have different runtime-switchable operating modes that give you different instruction sets). Non-thumb presumably means `arm`.
- `hard` refers to an ABI-variant determining how floating-point arguments are passed to functions (this is now deprecated AFAIK).
- The libraries not having `armv7-a` in the path are presumably for the now-deprecated `armeabi` (i.e. ARMv5TE).

Comment: so would that mean the the `armv7-a/libgcc.a` should be used then?

Comment: Either that or the `armv7-a/thumb` variant. Normally you would not explicitly invoke the linker, and the build system would pick the right version of the library for you.

Comment: well, I am invoking from a custom build script, and for this reason I have to provide a pointer to the directory containing libgcc.a (using `-L` switch).

Comment: If you're using a custom build script then you'll want to use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) to deal with these kinds of issues for you. You should never need to use `-L` for system libraries like libgcc. If you can't use a standalone toolchain for some reason, the flag you're looking for is `-gcc-toolchain`.

Comment: thanks, I found that after reviewing all the issues on github :) While trying to undersand the exceptions issues, I started to wonder if the problem was not with which libgcc ld was using... but as you saw on the github issue, it was not the case :)